# What is the correct way to update data/rows in a QAbstractTableModel backed by a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following class derived from QAbstractTableModel

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import List, Any
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class DataModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
  data_updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

  def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()):
    super(DataModel, self).__init__()
    self._data = data

  def update_data(self, data: pd.DataFrame):
    self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0, self.rowCount())
    self._data = data
    self.endInsertRows()
    self.data_updated.emit()

  def data(self, index, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
      return str(self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()])

  def rowCount(self, index = None) -> int:
    return self._data.shape[0]
  
  def columnCount(self, index = None) -> int:
    return self._data.shape[1]

  def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation, role: int ) -> Any:
    # section is the index of the column/row.
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
      if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
        return str(self._data.columns[section])
      if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
        return str(self._data.index[section])
```

The issue I have is that when I update the data in the `DataModel` using `update_data`, I'm passing in a full dataframe and replacing the existing dataframe. This is probably not the right way to do it since I see examples online of modifying rows one by one. The current method seems to cause a segfault over time e.g. after multiple data updates. I also occasionally get these types of errors:

```
QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows:  Invalid index ( 36 , 0 ) in model QSortFilterProxyModel(0x55b4e0d007f0)
```

This model is used in the following way:

```
class DataView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(DataView, self).__init__()

    self.model = DataModel()

    self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
    self.view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    self.view.setStyleSheet('alternate-background-color: grey;background-color: white;')

    self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

    self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
```

Is the right way to do this to diff the old dataframe and the new dataframe and individually update those rows in `DataModel`? Is there a better way of doing this? I would prefer to keep the dataframe as the backing datastructure if possible.

Comment: The last argument of `beginInsertRows` is the number of the *new* last row, it cannot nor should be the *current* row count. You must compute it based on the *start* row (the insertion row) and the length of the new data: if you're adding two rows at row 0, then it should be `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 1)`: last = first + len(new_data) - 1.

Comment: oh wow, so would it be "safe" to just take the rowcount of the new incoming dataframe then? so basically `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, len(data))` ?

Comment: If you always intend to *insert* data starting from the first row, yes. Your code didn't work because you probably inserted a data count different than `rowCount() - 1`, and both views and proxy models *must* receive the `rowsAboutToBeInserted` and `rowsInserted` signals with correct arguments, otherwise they wouldn't know what to do with the new model size. For instance, if you call `update_data` with the empty model, the connected objects would receive a *one* row insertion (first=last=0, meaning that you're adding *one* row at index 0), but if the data has more rows, that would be wrong.

Comment: In my opinion, technically you do not update a model in sense of updating of existent items. You are resetting a model, moreover your updated data can lead to item count changes. Update presumes the changes of existent items as I have said, and emitting a `dataChanged` signal. And in your case it would be correct to use `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel` with replacement of model data.

Comment: I did not know of `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel`! I think that works better for my purposes, thank you!

Comment: while `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel` do work, it's extremely slow for large number of entries (I have 3000+ entries). Specifiying rows/columns added using `beginInsertRows` and `beingInsertColumns` is much more performant